# What is better to return from the controller - a JsonResult or a string?

Tags: web-development, .net, asp.net, web-api

I have a WebAPI application and I have a controller method which is used to return a json result to the UI.

Now, I can either return a string (because the json is basically a string - and it works properly), or I can return a JsonResult from System.Web.Http.Results.

Are there any advantages to using the JsonResult?

Comment: Returning JSON is always recommended. There are various reasons, the most important and foremost is interoperatibility. Almost every device understands JSON and accepts JSON as return type. And from dev's point of view, parsing JSON is much simpler than parsing String. Think of it as an serialized form of whole object. So you can map it to objects on backend or if you are using jQuery, then parsing JSON is like a breeze.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends. How is the result meant or expected to be used?

If it should be a string (i.e. no associated json semantics), then return it as a string.

If you wish to use of the facilities associated with the json data, then keep the `JsonResult`.

**If you are unsure, keep the `JsonResult` and let the client convert it if they require it to be just a string.**